# How do I enable SLI on an Alienware m9750?

Tags: nvidia

I have a Alienware m9750 with dual 7950 gtx go's. I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed.. I installed the newest drivers, and had no issues with just installing the drivers... i went to terminal and did

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --sli=On
```

reboot

once doing this and reboot came... i saw the Nvidia logo splash screen (not sure if I was supposed to) then the system continually would try to load into ubuntu gui... and then just show some of the processes (text) and then just show nvidia splash screen and continually do this... never showing the GUI. I had to reinstall to get it working again. I tried to boot to recovery mode and edit the xorg.conf file, but kept saying read only, and wouldn't let me change it. Any help would be nice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing mode of file from read-only to read and write:

```
sudo chmod +rw xorg.conf
```

and then after editing you can make it read-only:

```
sudo chmod -w xorg.conf
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response... I've been scouring the web and my brain was hurting trying to figure out how to make the files not read only! Also, which command should I use to enable SLI.?    sudo nvidia-xconfig --sli=On or sudo nvidia-xconfig --sli=AFR